# Is it possible to draw straight edge which connects some specified points inside nodes but draws arrow at the intersection with node's side?

Tags: cytoscape.js

By default edge connects two node centers and arrows are drawn as I want - near the node's side. I need to have almost the same with the only exception that not centers are connected but some specified points of nodes which have rectangular shape, something like on the picture:
[edge picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSB6s.png)

I found a way to draw edge which connects points I need, here is the code:

```
    .selector('edge')
    .css({
        'curve-style': 'straight',
        'source-endpoint': '25% 0',
        'target-endpoint': '-25% 0',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
        ...
    })
```

The problem is that arrow is not visible in this case, is there a way to have arrow at node's side as shown on the picture?